# strange log4net initialization behavior

Tags: c#, log4net

I have run into some strange behavior with log4net and wondered if anyone can explain this to me, I would love to learn more to understand it.

Inside my WPF App.xaml.cs OnStartup override method I have the following code which sets a log4net property used for logging:

```
// logLocation is a path to a subdir in the users' appdata roaming dir
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogLocation"] = logLocation;
logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App));
logger.Info("OnStartup: " + string.Join(" ", e.Args));
```

I do this before I create any other loggers (or so I thought).

In my config file I have the following line:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogLocation}" />
```

This works to specify the logging file location.  However, I have run into a situation in which this fails - resulting in logging writing to a file name "(null)" in the executing directory.

What seems to cause this is the following pseudo code, which is in the same OnStartup method after the code above:

```
AnyClass ac = new AnyClass();
ac.NoOp();
```

where AnyClass has a logger instantiated like this:

```
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AnyClass));
```

The reason I am using pseudo code, is that I can replicate this behavior with any class I instantiate AND call a method on.  If no method is called, then the logging path works as expected.

A couple of things to note:

1. This works when I run it in the debugger in debug or release mode.  The error only appears when I run the exe directly or via 'Start Without Debugging'.
2. If the logger is not defined statically - then the problem goes away
3. If I add a static constructor to AnyClass, then the problem goes away, i.e.:

   static AnyClass() {}
4. If I move the call to ac.NoOp() to a secondary method, which is called by OnStartup - the error goes away.

So, to recap, the error is only caused by instantiating a class with a static logger initialization, and invoking a method on that class within the OnStartup method.

I have several ways to work around this, but I would love to learn more to understand why this is happening.

Comment: You can probably learn more by reading the Jon Skeet articles linked in Marc Gravell's answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965976/when-do-static-variables-get-initialized-in-c

Comment: Thanks, will read this. Apparently static initialization is not quite as straightforward as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ac.NoOp();` is creating a **new instance** of logger and new instance does not know what is value of PatternString. hence `null` value is being used.

[refer this link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
public static Logger getLogger(String name)

Retrieve a logger named according to the value of the name parameter. 

If the named logger already exists, then the existing instance will be returned. 
Otherwise, **a new instance** is created.
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter since the property is not per logger.