# Two errors that I can't fix

Tags: c#, process, int

I get two errors every time that say

1) A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property `Program.csProcess`

2) `foreach` statement cannot operate on variables of type `decimal` because `decimal` does not contain a public definition for `GetEnumerator`

```
 {
    Process[] csProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    static var modules = csProcess.Modules;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (ProcessModule module in modules)
        {
            if (module.ModuleName == "client.dll")
            {
                // do stuff
            }
```

Comment: Why is `modules` a `decimal`? Why is any of this outside `Main`?

Comment: I don't know I'm not an experienced coder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Process[] csProcess is *not* static. Frankly, modules shouldn't be either.

2) You can't use var outside of a method. Use ProcessModuleCollection instead.

Static variables, methods, etc. are scoped to the application, whereas member (non-static variables, methods, etc.) belong to the instance of the class/struct that you create.

This gives more info on when static variables are instantiated:
[When do static variables get initialized in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965976/when-do-static-variables-get-initialized-in-c)

You could refactor your code like this if you wanted to keep those variables global to the application:

```
public class Program
{
    static Process csProcess;
    static ProcessModuleCollection modules;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        csProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
        if (csProcess == null) { return; } // notepad isn't running
        modules = csProcess.Modules;
        foreach (ProcessModule module in modules)
        {
            if (module.ModuleName == "client.dll")
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

The current answer takes the first notepad process it finds, and loops through its modules. If you want to check *every* notepad process that it finds, you need to remove `.First()`, change `Process` to `Process[]`, and loop through: `foreach (var process in csProcess) { //code }`

But I'd advise learning the difference between static and instance variables ASAP.

Comment: this fixed the errors but made another one.   'Process[]' does not contain a definition for 'modules' and no extension method 'modules' accepting a first argument of type 'Process[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)