# In C# set value to a constant property

Tags: c#, constants

I am partly modifying an application where I will need to set value of the following constant to the value of the environment variable **if exists**.

What I already have:

```
private const string BuildPackagePath = @"\\server\build\";
```

What I would like to do is:

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvVar") != null)
Set the property value to = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvVar")
else
{Keep default/assigned value}
```

I understand that the left side of an asignment has to be a variable. I will probably have to change the type but was just wondering if anyone could give me an idea so the structure of current code can be kept as is.

Comment: You can´t modify a constants value, that´s why it´s called *constant*. However you can use `readonly` to indicate that the member can be modified only within the constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to check

Comment: For most intends and purposes `static readonly` will work like `const` *at runtime*. If you need a compile time constant, you can't use it of course. -- so you could have `private static readonly string BuildPackagePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvVar") ?? @"\\server\build\";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using a static property without setter

```
// evaluates Environment Variable on each call
private static string BuildPackagePath 
{
    get { return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvVar") ?? @"\server\build\"; }
}
```

static readonly field will evaluate Environment Variable only once (but not immediately at startup [When do static variables get initialized in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965976/when-do-static-variables-get-initialized-in-c))

```
private static readonly string BuildPackagePath = 
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvVar") ?? @"\server\build\";
```

Comment: Mind that this is evaluated every time the getter is called ... if in the course of runtime the EnvVar is set, the result could change.

Comment: @Fildor, yes. it maybe desired, or not. if not, then `static readonly` field instead of property should work, since it is initialized once. `readonly` instance field will reevaluate EnvironmentVariable for every new object. many options, choose depending on requirements

Comment: I agree, it *could* be desired. I just wanted to point that behavior out to avoid "surprises".

Answer (score 2):

You can´t modify a constants value, that´s why it´s called *constant*. However you can use `readonly` to indicate that the member can be modified only within the constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly string BuildPackagePath;
    public MyClass()
    {
        var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvVar");
        if(value != null) this.BuildPackagePath = value;
        else this.BuildPackagePath = @"\server\build\";
    }
}
```

Or even shorter using the [null-conitional operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator):

```
this.BuildPackagePath = value ?? @"\server\build\";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "readonly" modifier instead of const. Then you can set a value of the field in a constructor of a class. For example:

```
class SampleClass
{
      public int x;
      // Initialize a readonly field
      public readonly int y = 25;
      public readonly int z;

      public SampleClass()
      {
         // Initialize a readonly instance field
         z = 24;
      }
}
```