# Static class isn't initialized if list is defined with own type

Tags: c#, list, class, static, initialization

I have a static class with strings for example for path definitions but it is also used for static lists.
Now I have the problem that when I start my launcher that my static class got not initialized when I write list (s) into my static class.

Exmaple:

```
static class Data
{
    public static string path_1 = "B:\myFolder\test.txt";
}
```

-- > Class will be initialized when program starts (Data.path_1 = "B:\myFolder\test.txt")

```
 class MyObject
 {
      string name = null;
      object data = null;
 }

static class Data
{
    public static string path_1 = "B:\myFolder\test.txt";

    public static list<MyObject> myList = new list<MyObject>();
}
```

-- > Class **won't** be initialized when program starts (Data.path_1 = null, Data.myList = null)

When the program query the value, I get an expection:

> **TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for #Module# threw an exception**
>
> ***inner exception***
>
> **FileNotFoundException: The file or assembly "System.Runtime, Version = 4.2.2.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or a dependency on it was not found. The system can not find the stated
> file.**

A static class only with lists like from type "string" or "ScrollViewer" (WPF-Control) works.

NOTE:
My lists use own objects which are in my own library or in my program

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the whole project

**problem solved**

Answer (score -1):

Static variables will be initialized when you try to use them

[When do static variables get initialized in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965976/when-do-static-variables-get-initialized-in-c)

Your problem is exactly what the exception says, you need to import the package System.Runtime

This might help you

[Visual Studio 2017 - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4)

Comment: But I have allready that package:

<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />

And I get the Error when i try to use them